# Is it possible to limit a radio button choice, based on the previous radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Basically I have a survey, where I want people to rank 5 items 1-5 based on importance.

Here is the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/madcaesar/jj8ky/

```
<form>
    <table>
    <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" class="altTH" style="text-align:left">Please rank, in order of most important (1) to least important (5)</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Professionalism (promoting the profession of medicine)</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Professionalism" value="1" class="checkbox"/> 1</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Professionalism" value="2" class="checkbox"/> 2</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Professionalism" value="3" class="checkbox"/> 3</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Professionalism" value="4" class="checkbox"/> 4</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Professionalism" value="5" class="checkbox"/> 5</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Government Relations (state and federal government advocacy)</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="GovernmentRelations" value="1" class="checkbox"/> 1</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="GovernmentRelations" value="2" class="checkbox"/> 2</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="GovernmentRelations" value="3" class="checkbox"/> 3</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="GovernmentRelations" value="4" class="checkbox"/> 4</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="GovernmentRelations" value="5" class="checkbox"/> 5</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr><tr>
                    <th><label>Education (e.g. CME, staff training, meetings)</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Education" value="1" class="checkbox"/> 1</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Education" value="2" class="checkbox"/> 2</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Education" value="3" class="checkbox"/> 3</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Education" value="4" class="checkbox"/> 4</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Education" value="5" class="checkbox"/> 5</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Regulatory and legal analysis and support</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Regulatory" value="1" class="checkbox"/> 1</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Regulatory" value="2" class="checkbox"/> 2</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Regulatory" value="3" class="checkbox"/> 3</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Regulatory" value="4" class="checkbox"/> 4</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Regulatory" value="5" class="checkbox"/> 5</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label>Communications (Iowa Medicine magazine, website, media relations, etc.)</label></th>
                    <td>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Communications" value="1" class="checkbox"/> 1</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Communications" value="2" class="checkbox"/> 2</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Communications" value="3" class="checkbox"/> 3</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Communications" value="4" class="checkbox"/> 4</label>
                        <label style="display:inline"><input type="radio" name="Communications" value="5" class="checkbox"/> 5</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Is it possible with jQuery to make 1 unavailable once 1 has been selected once? and 2 once 2 has been selected and so forth? Right now they can select any number they want, and I can't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: It's definitely possible but I'm not sure it's a good idea. Once the user has ranked all 5 items then their answers are basically going to be locked. You could switch to checkboxes so they could un-check a rank so they can select it on another item... but that seems clumsy for the user.

Comment: I certainly could switch to checkboxes. That's a very good point your raised as far as them being locked in. I'm still unsure how to code this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this, where if you select a certain number, it unselects any others that have the same value?:

http://jsfiddle.net/jj8ky/2/

```
$("#radio_table").on("click", ".checkbox", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var all = $("#radio_table").find(".checkbox").not($this);
    var val = $this.val();

    if ($this.prop("checked") === true) {
        all.filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() === val;
        }).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking

Comment: This is a fantastic solution! I didn't even think of it this way. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Amir Cool, glad you like it. It can still be a little frustrating for the user if the radio buttons are all close to each other, but otherwise it seems to do as you asked

Answer (score -2):

You can disable some radio when needed : ex

```
if($("#radio").val()==2) $("#otherRadio").attr("disabled",true);
```